# Recursive Function conversion

Tags: python, arrays, recursion

My def "gennums" first uses some random values (randomindices) generated by a separate Def, it returns a new set of indices which is then used by the next step, ... etc recursively.

these are the manual steps:

```
s1 = gennums(arr,randomindices,9)

s2 = gennums(arr,s1,8)

s3 = gennums(arr,s2,7)

s4 = gennums(arr,s3,6)

s5 = gennums(arr,s4,5)

s6 = gennums(arr,s5,4)

s7 = gennums(arr,s6,3)

s8 = gennums(arr,s7,2)

s9 = gennums(arr,s8,1)
```

I want it to work recursively n number of times until the third argument reaches 1..

something like this..

```
def dorecusive(nums):

  count = nums:

  s1 = gennums(arr,randomindices,count)

  count-=1

  while count != 0:
    s2 =(genums,s1,count)
    s1=s2
    return (genums,s1,count)
```

Comment: Recursively? Do you mean iteratively?

Comment: Try storing [s1...s9] inside a list then looping over. Set s0 = randomindices.

Comment: i want to do: def function(nums) and the nums count down to 1, so it repeats until count reaches 1

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea about python so please ignore my syntactic mistake.

```
def gennums(arr, randomindices, count) 
    if count === 1
        return;
    return gennums(arr, randomindices, count--)
```

Comment: The randomindies have to change each time, using the values returned from genums